# Lumia 520 battery draining fast

Tags: lumia-520, battery

Why is my Lumia 520 battery draining too fast? At 4.00am when I charge phone to 100% within an hour it is completely drained to 0%.

Comment: Have you checked battery settings to see which apps are using the battery?

Comment: Yes i checked and have put off some of the apps. But the problem still persists

Comment: Your battery may be damaged . Try to bring out the test shop

Answer (score 1):

The simple truth here is that the Lumia 520 has an extremely small battery in it. The battery in the Lumia 520 is 1430mAh which is considered extremely small.

The other thing is that the Lumia 520 still runs on Windows 8 Mobile.

So those are the two factors that cause your phone battery to be drained so fast. There's nothing you can do about this. You either need to buy a new battery for short term better battery or buy a new phone for long term better battery.

Comment: The phone is Lumia 540 and it is having Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: @redeemer The question says Lumia 520 and not 540. You'll have to ask a seperate question for Lumia 540 as it's a completely different phone.